# Should I start to use Windows Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have just gotten Visual Studio 2010 Pro Academic Version today with the MSDN Free Azure service.

I was wondering should I start develpering it now or start at a latter stage. I have just started to program with .NET and C# but should I learn Azure now or wait untill it is mainstream?

Should I buy more data then the Pro MSDN or just use the default data?

Thanks in advance.

Benny.

Comment: what do you mean by mainstream.. its already used by many. It depends upon what are your business requirements.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro sorry but I mean when neally everybody uses it and it becomes reall.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest being a late adopter.  You're working in a field where early adopters win.  There are rumors that Steve Jobs was working on the iPad 10 years ago.  Where would Apple be if they waited for things to become "more mainstream"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you learn something today that isn't yet mainstream, then when it does go mainstream, you might just be an expert that people will pay handsomely for some consulting work.

Also, consider where your product is?  Do you really need something super stable and super secure for something you haven't even built yet?  I find that by the time I have an application I've built finally come to market, the tools I've used that were "Beta" are now widely used, mainstream, and stable.

Keep in mind that technology moves fast.  I've seen developers use tools in a new project that became obsolete by the time the project went to production.

With that said, I agree with Shekar_Pro, Azure, and many other cloud based services, are already widely used and adopted.

Answer (score 4):

If you are just beginning with .Net and C# then I would say no. Its not the time for you to move on to using Azure... but then others might disagree with me. so its your own opinion.

However you don't need to wait it to be mainstream.. Many are already using it  extensively. Even if you think its not as much in demand (from job perspective) in your locality then also learning anything thats goin to be used anyway and will become mainstream will make you an expert by then... Its totally depend upon business situation. An other answer has shed some light on this